# Twython and Twitter API: Who unfollowed a Twitter User Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twython

I am currently trying to explore Twitter APIs with Twython. I am familiar with get followers, list, and so on. But is there a way I can find out the list of unfollowers for a specific user and their timeline by using Python ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not very sure what you want. Do you want to know the names of the followers who unfollow a user at a specific time? Is your case the same as the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772623/twitter-api-who-unfollowed-from-me

Comment: Yes, precisely. Thank you